# In what episode does Anakin get his padawan (Ahsoka) in Star Wars : The Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I'm trying to watch the Cartoon Network's CGI *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* from the very beginning, but the version that Netflix has, is when Anakin and Ahsoka ***already*** are master/pupil.

Where or how can I google to watch the show from the very beginning? As in, since when Anakin gets Ahsoka. I watched the show live when it aired and I've been able to find clips, but no full video or anything.

Comment: Since Donmax already answered your question, I'll just point out that the movie is also available on Netflix and that if you are satisfied with Donmax's answer you should accept it by clicking on the check mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 21):

The [*Clone Wars movie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_%28film%29), not an episode per se.

Wikipedia offers a synopsis:

> With the help of Obi-Wan Kenobi and Anakin Skywalker, the clones steadily advance on the Separatists' forces, gaining the Republic an early victory. It doesn't last long, though, as the droid army soon returns. With no communications or the ability to fly in reinforcements, the fate of the few remaining clone soldiers are in the hands of Obi-Wan and Anakin.
>
> A shuttle arrives, but without the needed reinforcements. **Instead, it is a young Padawan named Ahsoka Tano, who insists that she has been sent by Master Yoda to serve under Anakin.** The battle soon commences yet again, with the Separatist forces advancing behind an expanding energy shield that artillery can't penetrate. Anakin and Ahsoka succeed in penetrating the enemy lines while Obi-Wan stalls for time by holding a fake surrender negotiation with the droid army commander.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, Donmax. Try to back them up more fully though...

Answer (score -1):

Sadly this is not an episode on Netflix. There is no episode where Ahsoka is appointed to Anakin Skywalker by Yoda. However, I do know what scenes you are talking about. There is a Star Wars: The Clone Wars movie. That is where you will find the "before" Star Wars the Clone Wars T.V. series. The movie has Ahsoka meeting Anakin, Captain Rex, and the first appearance of the Separatist forces. They also return Jabba the Hutt's son in this movie.

Comment: I fail to see how this adds anything useful to the existing answer

Comment: This has already been covered by existing answers. Do you have anything new to add?